# Unable to install 12.10 on asus r500v

Tags: installation

I have been unable to get beyond the grub boot screen of the live dvd/usb.

The *Try Ubuntu without installing*, *Install Ubuntu*, etc menu shows, and I have tried adding and replacing `nomodeset` and `no splash` with neither helping.

Even *Check disc for defects* does not display anything when selected.  I am at a complete loss as to how to fix this one.  I have had many successful installs in the past, but this is definitely a first for me.

Just as FYI,
Gfx card: Geforce GT 635M

I realize this particular card has Optimus on it, however even the alternative boot/command line install fails to load.

Any help would be appreciated.

I realize there have been multiple threads on this, but none of the methods within them have solved this yet.

As reference, I have followed the following page: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076)

Moreover, I have confirmed that the particular iso that I have burned can be booted through Virtual Box.

Comment: Have to you checked the md5sum off the downloaded iso file?

Comment: Yes, the md5 matches https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch off in BIOS the option "Fast Start" or something like this from the Boot tab. Probably you problem has nothing with the graphics.